# Cron job execution on terminal */5 * * * * ./executeFiles.ksh

Tags: linux, cron

Cron job execution on terminal */5 * * * * ./executeFiles.ksh

Facing this exception:

```
sri@Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/JAVA$ */5 * * * * ./executeFiles.ksh
bash: */5: No such file or directory
```

I am trying to execute this script every 5 minutes, and when I passed the command as */5 * * * * ./executeFiles.ksh
It says bash: */5: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 2):

Cron jobs have to be "created" with

```
crontab -e
```

Use an absolute path for the specified command and not a relative path. Also make sure all commands called in the script are found regarding the general PATH setting or address them absolute as well.